# Reading a .md file applying some regex, giving null in JavaScript/TS

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, readfile

I have changelog.MD file I am reading it through, fs in JavaScript like,

```
const readFile = async (fileName: string) => {
  return promisify(fs.readFile)(filePath, 'utf8');
}
```

now reading my .md file:

```
const readMD = async (filePath: string) => {
  const text = await readFile(filePath);
}
```

content in changelog.md is:

```
## asdfasdf
 * 11asdf asdf
 * 11asdfadf
 
## asdfadf
 * asdfasf
 * asdfasdf
```

function to read it and applying regex like:

```
const changeLog = await readME(changeLogPath);
const result = changelog.match(/^##.*\n([^#]*)/m);
console.log(final[1]);
```

btw- this regex is working fine and returns me the first bullets under first ##. ie. output.

```
 * 11asdf asdf
 * 11asdfadf
```

but it returns null, when I apply it on the result after reading changelog.MD file. Any help.

Comment: What does mean "regex is working fine but it returns null"?

Comment: please check my edited answer.

Comment: By the way, in newer versions of Node you just have to `const fs = require("fs/promises")` to use promisified fs.

Comment: What happens when you `consol.log(final)`?

Comment: Why is `readFile` an async function when it already returns a promise and you're not using `await`?

Comment: Wait a minute, where is the `final` variable defined?? Also, `changeLog` is camel cased while `changelog.match(...)` is lowercase. Typos?

Comment: I don't see the `readME` method defined, or `final` - you sure you don't just have typos?

Comment: Also, try `console.log(result)`. Sorry for the amount of comments, but I know the bug definitely lies somewhere there.

Comment: There are so many inconsistent variable name uses in the code. How did you get it to run??

Comment: Sorry about the typos, I directly wrote code here, I couldn't copy paste, as that was in remote machine (not allowed). So there is no typos in the code. I am trying the answer given by @artyom below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert on TypeScript but when I tried the same with pure JS it worked.

```
const fs = require("fs");

const readMD = (filePath) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", (error, content) => {
            if (error) reject(error);
            resolve(content);
        });
    });
}

readMD("./changelog.md").then(changelog => {
    const result = changelog.match(/^##.*\n([^#]*)/m);
    console.log(result[1]);
});
```

Comment: Hey Artyom, my regex is working fine, I am able to get the first bullets (which is my requirement), my issue is when I run it on static strings(string literal) it works fine, but when I do the same while reading a file and applying this regex on that, it returns null. Are you referring the same solution above?

Comment: Ok, let me try that way

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for getting delayed in sharing my solution:

The regex works fine but the original issue was in regex only-  the right one is below.

`(/^##.\r*([^#]*)/m);`